# How to extract data from url fetch response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I implemented a fetch method using Google Script and it returns me the following log:

```
[16-06-10 14:06:03:942 EEST] {
  "accessToken": "data",
  "userId": 3096,
  "created": "2016-06-10T05:06:03.799-06:00"
}
```

Does anyone know how can I extract the value from `accessToken` ?

Here is my gs code:

```
  var url = "https://example.com"
  var payload = {
    'username' : "user",
    'password' : "pass",
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(urlResponse); //this returns me the log shown above
```

Basically I want to add the "data" value from `accessToken` to a variable `getData`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but I'll try. Do you want to have the value of accessToken?

`var getData = urlResponse.accessToken`

Comment: Yes, I want to have the value from `accessToken` stored in a variable. Unfortunately your solution does not work, I get `undefined` on the variable `getData`

Comment: The `getData` variable must contain `data` value (from `accessToken`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that even if the variable urlResponse look to be an object it will only return you some string value. You should try to do something like that:

```
var data = JSON.parse(urlResponse.getContentText());
Logger.log(data.accessToken);
```

Comment: Thank you, makes a lot of sense!